# Java Runtime Environment EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, jvm

Acabo de realizar una app de escritorio con java swing, creando un .exe con JLaunch a partir del .jar con el JRE embebido, al ejecutar dicho .exe me aparece un archivo log en la carpeta de ejecución con lo siguiente:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb753d1d65, pid=9052, tid=9036
#
# JRE version:  (20.0.1+9) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, unknown gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jimage.dll+0x1d65]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
#
```

He estado indagándo en internet, y veo que dicen que el archivo jimage.dll pudiera estar dañado, pero lo he sustituido por otro, inclusive descargando nuevamente el openjdk 20 pero el error persiste.

Lo interesante de esto, es que este mismo programa sí funciona en otros equipos (hasta ahora), sólo es uno en el que aparece este error. El detalle es que este aplicativo está pensado para instalarse en varios equipos y me gustaría saber el origen de éste error para poder solventarlo en caso de que sucediera nuevamente.

Comment: ¿Probaste _jugar_ con otras versiones de OpenJDK, a ver si se da el mismo error?

Comment: Hola Cristian, has probado ejecutar el **.jar** que creas?, porque podría ser que hayas omitido alguna librería en el.

Comment: @padaleiana , muchas gracias.... no, no lo he intentado, porque el OpenJDK que uso para compilar es el 20, el problema es que entiendo que la versión 20 del openjdk es la más actual y si la pruebo con una menor pudiera mandarme error porque la versión con la que está compilada es con la 20.

Comment: @padaleiana . Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, no, no lo he intentado con otra versión. entiendo que la versión 20 es la más actual, y si pruebo con una versión menor, quizás me tire un error porque el jdk que uso para compilar es el 20.

Comment: @MarcePuente si, si probé a ejecutar el jar y ahí si se ejecuta sin problemas, sólo es el exe :(

Comment: ¿Cambiaste de jLaunch a Launch4j, por ejemplo? Aparte decís _quizá me tire un error_... Tenés que probarlo, o empaquetarlo con una versión menor, por qué no :)

Comment: Si te manejas con el ingles (o usas traductor) puedes ver [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation).

Comment: @padaleiana, no, siempre usé el Launch4j, lo intentaré, aunque éste error apareció de pronto, es decir, siempre genero de la misma manera el .exe y el equipo donde tiró el error, anteriormente ya había funcionado con el mismo openjdk, fue de pronto cuando comenzó a fallar.

Comment: @MarcePuente Muchas gracias, efectivamente ya me lo había leído, pero al bajar la versión me marcaba el error de que el jdk compilado el código originalmente era mayor al que se intentaba ejecutar actualmente. Esto es brujería, lo que hicimos fue mantener 2 versiones del **mismo** openjdk, por alguna razón con una de ellas si corría bien y con otra no :(

Comment: ¿Y si el openjdk _que no funcionaba_ era en realidad un archivo corrupto?

Comment: Christian, existe la posibilidad de que un determinado JDK, no pueda ejecutar un programa compilado con otra versión, tanto si esta es mayor como si es menor (en un caso puede tener clases que estaban marcadas como "deprecated" y fueron removidas, y en el otro, puede estar invocando clases que no existen en esa versión).